# using google.maps.visualRefresh in v3.11 gives wrong position for custom infowindows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have been encouraged to use this new style feature whilst waiting for the v3.14 release.

However, when enabling this (*with  google.maps.visualRefresh=true*), the positions of custom infowindows can be corrupted.

This is because there is a change in one of the css styles.
Google Maps now defines the following :

```
.gm-style div
{
    display: block;
}
```

So, if you have defined your custom infowindow container as a DIV having a class with a style of

```
display: inline-block;
```

this will override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present workaround for this, obviously, is to add **!important** to the style :

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

Google : please update documentation or remove this style.